# Can't debug Python script in PyCharm 5.0: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'default_getpass'`

Tags: python, pycharm

I have PyCharm Community Edition 5.0

I copy/pasted the code from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/27831/5117) in a file called `toolbars.py`. If I run it, I get a `KeyError: 'offer_urls'`.

So I wanted to try to debug the script in PyCharm. I right-clicked on the script, selected `Debug 'toolbars'` but then I got the following error output in the console window:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 57391 --file C:/Users/BioGeek/Documents/temp/toolbars.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pydevd_breakpoints import * #@UnusedWildImport
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd_breakpoints.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pydevd_comm import GetGlobalDebugger
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 71, in <module>
    import pydevconsole
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 18, in <module>
    fix_getpass.fixGetpass()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0\helpers\pydev\fix_getpass.py", line 9, in fixGetpass
    fallback = getpass.default_getpass # <= 2.5
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'default_getpass'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This seems to me like there is an error/bug in the code for PyCharm itself. How can I resolve this so that I can debug the script?

Comment: If you think it's a bug in PyCharm you should ask JetBrains, not SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I had a file called `getpass.py` in the folder where my `toolbar.py` script was located. So that file was imported instead of the `getpass`module.